# Display image cropped

Tags: html, css

How can I display an image with a 100% width and fixed height, but not resized. I mean, the part that doesn't fit the fixed dimensions to be cropped. E.g.:

Low resolution view:

[image]

High resolution view:

[image]

(not exactly, all images should fit the same % width and the same height pixels)

This could be the code:

HTML:

```
<a id="image">
    <img src="url" />
</a>
```

CSS:

```
#image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Is using the image as background-image an option?

Comment: use text-align, line-height for #img and give negative margin to img to reduce virtually its size to 0 and it will tand in the middle of the box or any where else depending on tunning margin

Comment: @GCyrillus Comments are used for clarification, not answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I've achieved it:

```
#image {           /* the parent element */
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden; 
    height: 250px; 
}

#image > img {     /* the image */
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168578/display-image-cropped/21168666#21168666), and it might help you some:

[3 Easy and Fast CSS Techniques for Faux Image Cropping](http://cssglobe.com/3-easy-and-fast-css-techniques-for-faux-image/)

Comment: Your Welcome! Glad I could help! Remember, if this helped, upvote it, and if it fixed your problem, accept it as an answer!

Comment: Yes, it is... the last one

Comment: Ah, didn't see it. I see it now.

Answer (score 2):

you may use text-align and line-height on parent and reduce virtually size of image with negative margin:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqoEg

```
#image {
  height:200px;
  line-height:200px;/* same value as height, classic method for valign */
  text-align:center;/* horizontal center inline boxe / text */
  width:50%;
  margin:2em auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:solid;
}

#image img {
  margin: -250px -100%; /* reduce virtually initial size/space needed for the image */
  vertical-align:middle;/* center it on base-line */
}
/* demo purpose */
#image:hover {
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  margin:50px auto;
}
```

a few more examples : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/wsjBJ / http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/BdtEj and http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/etxky  this question comes up very often.
Easy way is background when image has no meaning in the content .

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems more complicated than I thought.

Comment: I've finally found an easier way (posted as answer). Thank you anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div>
    <div class = image> 
       <img src />
    </div>
</div> 

.image {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: -50%;
  }
```

Comment: By nesting the image in a div with a class set to relative positioning, overflow hidden and half the width and height of the image we can crop off the excess.